# Excel, finding the highest date value from a list with duplicate values

Tags: excel

I have a deep column A with IDs and each ID has in next column B date value.

Problem is that A contains up to 4 duplicate values at different places, thus e.g. 25430 could be there 4 times with different dates, e.g. 1.1.2014, 3.2.2015 etc.

I`d need to get into column C sorted column A - only 1 unique ID and if there are duplicate IDs in A then pick the highes date value.

Of course I could do it manually by sorting A by duplicate IDs and then manually delete other IDs with lower date but it`s not realistic to do it this way..

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

To identify the highest date value in ColumnB associated with each of the unique values in a labelled list in ColumnA:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))=B2
```

enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter and copy down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to do this with the following formula if you have this data:

```
    A             B
  Date          Rank
01/01/2015
01/01/2015
01/01/2015
02/02/2015
01/01/2014
03/03/2015
04/04/2015
04/04/2015
03/03/2015
04/04/4015
```

So in B2, you should put the following code:

```
=SUM(1*(A2>$A$2:$A$11))+1+IF(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2)=0,0,SUM(1*(A2=OFFSET($A$2,0,0,INDEX(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2)+1,1)-1,1))))
```

then CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER which will turn it into an array and drag it down, this is what you will end up with:

```
Date       Rank
01/01/2015  2
01/01/2015  3
01/01/2015  4
02/02/2015  5
01/01/2014  1
03/03/2015  6
04/04/2015  8
04/04/2015  9
03/03/2015  7
04/04/4015  10
```

1 Being the earliest date and 10 being the latest date.

I hope this helps :)